# Javascript: Good practice to load all the data when the page loads?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, pageload

I have a webpage in asp.net which uses [editable grid](http://www.editablegrid.net/en) to update/insert employee's records. A particular employee can have almost 50-70 attributes. Considering the frequent use of this page, I need to be very careful about the round trips to server and other I/O operations, as it might degrade the performance of page.

I am using a [jquery plugin](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/jQueryDLB.aspx?script=advanced) to choose from the given available columns. The left panel of listbox is populated using an xml file, which is read on server. The attributes are of multiple datatypes, such as simple string, integer or date.

The problem comes with the attributes which contain dropdown values, such as department, teams etc. Should I load the values of the dropdown values as the page loads in the start, irrespective of whether the user wishes to select the dropdowns or not? Or should I make another round trip to server and load the dropdown values of the selected attributes. Which approach should be used and why?

Note: There might be atmost 4 to 6 dropdown attributes, with maximum 30 to 40 values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on both the odds of the user needing that dropdownlist, and how badly you'll want to avoid additional Ajax loads.

This is a very specific issue. But if your dropdownlist items won't really change on a per-item basis, I'd go with loading them during pageload. Else, if one employee's dropdownlist won't be the same as the other's, use Ajax so you can get a custom dropdownlist every time.

But like I said, very specific for your particular situation.

Comment: Your key note here being *almost*. If it can change, I'd opt for using additional webcalls. Unless you *really* need to avoid those calls.

Comment: Well, If in case, a few attributes can hold upto 200 - 300 values? Then what do you suggest?

Comment: Generally speaking,  an Ajax call spends more time setting up the connection, waiting for a reaction from the server, and processing the received data. The actual data transfer is usually a fairly small portion of the time used, unless you have a very slow connection/webserver.